# Re enter in UK over weekend ICT visa

Tags: uk

I am on ICT visa(3years). Its been a month and I want to go to India to get my wife and son along and will be back within weekend(like going on Friday night and returning on Sunday) as I can not take leave from office as of now. Is there any limitation that once you leave UK you can come back only after X days or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an ICT visa you can travel freely 'to and fro' between UK/India as long as the visa hasn't expired.

If your child & wife has a visa you, can bring them without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

No, not even for Visitor visa holders or visa-free entry nationals.